# random soft wdt reset while request

Tags: esp8266, http

i am making post requests with esp8266 on nodeMCU. i have a messy code so i dont want to annoy you with showing it here. the problem is i get soft wdt reset time to time while making request. for example i change piece of code(removing or adding some `serial.println` lines) and i see i get soft wdt reset right there in `http.post`.

i tried my best to avoid Strings. I only used a few times, without in the loop. I am only using WiFiClientSecureBearSSL with FirebaseESP8266.

do you have any idea what cause this problem?

Comment: How are you powering the board?

Comment: with usb. i am not using without cable yet i am still dealing with these resets.

Comment: Connected direct you your computer? Not through an unpowered hub?

Comment: It is connected directly to the usb port. Why is there something wrong with it?

Comment: No. Quite the opposite. I have seen WDT timeouts when the board has been under-powered, but that's not the case here.

Comment: yeah. my problem is more like random here. i get wdt resets at diffrent requests. i thought maybe stack or heap reach each other but that is not related to soft wdt reset, is it?

Comment: It was the randomness that made me think power. But that's unlikely. A watchdog timeout could be caused by *anything* than makes execution go wrong.

Comment: Can usage of strings a few times cause memory fragmentation? Those Strings size are less than 100 characters.

Answer (score 3):

Show examples of the error - and install ESPexeption decoder to analyse the stack trace this will at least show why the wdt was caused
So the only thing as of now I can recommend
There is an issue with bearssl:

It's a WDT error caused by an extended SSL negotiation.

- Change the core frequency to 160MHz (if not already done) and try again.
- Use instead of LWIP1.4 (memory hog) low-mem LWIP2.0 with your program.
- Since SSL negotiation can take 5 seconds even at 160MHz for some websites be sure by adding a yield() not to trigger a wdt reset

So without code/ trace and error messages its hard to guess